# CSS animation not cycling through all images

Tags: css, css-animations

My application allows the user to select any number of images for the home page hero. I'm using CSS keyframe animation to cycle through these images. My animation works great  but once it gets to the end of the animation, instead of starting over with image 1 it only shows the last 4 images over and over.

Can anyone help?

```css
.banner-gallery img {
  position: absolute;
  animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

@keyframes slideShow {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.banner-gallery img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 36s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 42s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 48s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: 54s;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-gallery">
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-494985575.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-504284156.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-1249281377.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-1322290907.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-Waterfront-3499.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-Waterfront-8578.jpg" alt="waterfront home" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-Waterfront-9262.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-Waterfront-9949.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/IMG_5586.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/136-flyer-9-scaled.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you apply in your css more images as you have in your div container. Maybe a mistake?

Then you expect that the slideshow animation: slideShow (n)s long. But it takes longer. You have to calculate the animation-delays.  In the example below you have 8 images. every img has a animation-duration of 3 sec.  (8*3 = 24)

**working example for only three images**

```css
.banner-gallery img {
  position: absolute;
  animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}


@keyframes slideShow {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.banner-gallery img:nth-child(1) {  
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.banner-gallery img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 21s;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-gallery">  
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-494985575.jpg" alt="1" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-504284156.jpg" alt="2" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-1249281377.jpg" alt="3" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-1322290907.jpg" alt="4" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-Waterfront-3499.jpg" alt="5" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-Waterfront-8578.jpg" alt="6" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-Waterfront-9262.jpg" alt="7" />
  <img src="https://www.southflwaterfronthomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/WilsonTeam-Waterfront-9949.jpg" alt="8" />

</div>
```

Comment: If I sum all the animation delays then I would use slideShow 270s which does not work correctl?

Comment: @Junky no 270 sec :-). I update my answer with explanation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Even in your updated code snippet it is not cycling correctly after the first run through. It should start back with image 1 but it does not.

Comment: @Junky You are righ! I reproduce the example from https://www.mediaevent.de/tutorial/css-keyframes-slideshow.html . And the problem is the same. Then there is the problem that it skips the first picture. I have read in this context that CSS slideshows only do not really work. Better would be a Javascript solution or you reduce the number of images. Because with 3,4 it still worked well. With 7 pictures it shows the first picture only briefly. with 8 pictures it swallows the first one. Sorry!